# Display empty fullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to display an empty full calendar. I know that without input it displays nothing by default, but I can't find documentation on how to display the calendar with or without events.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a blank calendar to display using the code below:

However, this did not work with the version of Jquery that installs with MVC.  I couldn't get it working until I used the Jquery included in the fullCalendar zip file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar.css' />
  <script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar.js'></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //
      })

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Weird, it started showing up blank after I added the jquery from the zip and then removed it....

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue